# ansible \ any reason why .yml role element don't run roles/x/tasks/main.yml

Tags: ansible

I'm doing exactly like all the tutorials, don't have typos, and even able to run alone the main.yml inside /roles/x

but when I run the play that should call it - nothing really happens

parent

```
---
- name: Install / Upgrade tagger
  hosts: tagger
  roles:
    - tagger
```

/roles/tagger/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- command: echo 1
```

need to say I'm running everything in localhost.
tried also

```
 ansible-playbook -i "localhost" -c local tagger.yml
```

ansible-playbook -i "localhost" -c local tagger.yml

```
 [WARNING]: Host file not found: localhost

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [build tagger docker] *****************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Is your roles name `x` or `tagger`? The path to your `main.yml` should be `roles/tagger/tasks/main.yml`

Comment: tagger :) this is so weird...

Comment: Are you sure you call the correct playbook file? You show a file with a play named "Install / Upgrade tagger" but your output shows "build tagger docker".

Comment: Unrelated issue: add a comma after `localhost` in the ansible call: `-i "localhost,"`. Ansible is looking for a file named "localhost". By adding a comma it will interpret the input as a list of hostnames.

Comment: thanks (no warnings now) - issue remains

Comment: localhost isn't a `tagger` host. There's no mapping to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the commandline you gave:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i "localhost" -c local tagger.yml 
ERROR: Unable to find an inventory file, specify one with -i ?
```

With the obvious correction (adding a comma):

```
$ ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local tagger.yml 

PLAY [Install / Upgrade tagger] *********************************************** 
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
```

That still doesn't match your output, but it does indicate the problem. `localhost` is never `tagger`. Perhaps you are using a `hosts.ini` file and not telling us about it? Or a specific version of ansible that is different than mine? In any case, I changed `hosts: tagger` to `hosts: all` as follows:

```
---
- name: Install / Upgrade tagger
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - tagger
```

I then reran:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local tagger.yml

PLAY [Install / Upgrade tagger] *********************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [tagger | command echo 1] *********************************************** 
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

So there are the two fixes necessary.

Comment: wierd...did the two changes, still ignores the role..(I have ansible 2.1.0.0). I don't use any hosts.ini file - maybe I'll try that

Comment: also 2.1 on the other machine @user1025852?